# Is it possible to #[wasm_bindgen] public structs and functions defined in another crate?

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen

I have a crate `lib` that contains tons of structs and impls. Then I have another one called `web` that will make the portability of the core `lib` to the web. There is also `api` in case I want the app to be server-side.

- `myproject-api`
- `myproject-lib`
- `myproject-web`

What I don't want is to add all the `wasm` dependencies to `lib`, only in the `web` project and expose parts of the main library to the web. Is it possible to `#[wasm_bindgen]` the structs defined in the `myproject-lib` in `myproject-web`?

Comment: As far as I know: No. But there is an option to not always `#[wasm_bindgen]` the structs, using Rust's [conditional compilation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html) alongside [features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html) to only `#[wasm_bindgen]` when the crate that depends on lib requires it to

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not directly. The `#[wasm_bindgen]` attribute relies on being able to parse the struct and impls in order to generate the bindings. You would have to create wrapper types and functions for the attribute to bind to.

Say your `myproject-lib` looks like:

```
pub struct MyStruct {
    pub foo: i32,
}

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn bar(&self) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The bindings would be implemented in `myproject-web` like:

```
use myproject_lib::*;
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[wasm_bindgen(js_name = MyStruct)]
pub struct MyStructWrapper(MyStruct);

#[wasm_bindgen(js_class = MyStruct)]
impl MyStructWrapper {
    #[wasm_bindgen(getter)]
    pub fn foo(&self) -> i32 {
        self.0.foo
    }

    #[wasm_bindgen(setter)]
    pub fn set_foo(&mut self, value: i32) {
        self.0.foo = value;
    }

    pub fn bar(&self) {
        self.0.bar();
    }
}
```

As you can see, everything is done very explicitly.

- encapsulate the original struct and export it with the original name using [`js_name`](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/reference/attributes/on-rust-exports/js_name.html) and [`js_class`](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/reference/attributes/on-js-imports/js_class.html)
- list out and implement [getters and setters](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/reference/attributes/on-rust-exports/getter-and-setter.html) for public fields
- add simple forwarding functions to the original struct.

---

I believe the more widely-used method is to add the bindings to the original library but only enabled by a feature. This avoids much duplication, is less of a headache to implement, and ensures the bindings are always in-sync.

Add a `"wasm"` [feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html) that adds `wasm-bindgen` as an opt-in a dependency in your `Cargo.toml`:

```toml
[features]
wasm = ["wasm-bindgen"]

[dependencies]
wasm-bindgen = { version = "X.X.X", optional = true }
```

Then you can use [`cfg` and `cfg_attr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg-attribute) to only enable the `wasm_bindgen` attributes when the feature is enabled:

```
#[cfg(feature = "wasm")]
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[cfg_attr(feature = "wasm", wasm_bindgen)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    pub foo: i32,
}

#[cfg_attr(feature = "wasm", wasm_bindgen)]
impl MyStruct {
    pub fn bar(&self) {
        // do something
    }
}
```